# Can't get /RTCs to work in visual studio 2022 c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to find the source of a heap corruption in my project, and [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) that with `/RTCs` Visual Studio should detect array overrun.

However it does not seem to work, even though I am compiling and running in debug mode, with `/RTC1` and `/Od`.

```cpp
int main() {

    int* a = new int[5];
    a[100] = 0;

    int b[5];
    int c = sqrt(10000); // c = 100
    b[c] = 0;
    // b[100] = 0;    correctly triggers compilation error

    return 0;
}
```

This runs fine, but from my understanding it should not. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: visual studio is an IDE, it has no buisness in detecting something while you execute your program. Its your compiler that has a `/RTC` option (supposed it is msvc)

Comment: *"visual studio should detect array overrun."*  The problem here is that `a` is not an array, but a pointer. `b` *is* an array, so there it works.

Comment: @BoP though `b[c]` is out of bouds, and as I read the docs linked by OP i'd also expect /RTCs to detect it

Comment: For more thorough checks, you may want to use [AddressSanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand your current situation:

```
int* a = new int[5];
```

The right side of this statement is to build an array containing 5 integer elements by means of new, and the array is on the heap. On the left is a pointer a. According to my understanding, this pointer should be allocated to the stack by the system for processing, but the specific size of the stack and how much is left is uncertain. I think this has something to do with the system (it should be no matter to the size of the heap on the right).

And for this statement:

```
int b[5];
```

According to my understanding, b here is allocated a stack with a stack space size of "5 * 4 = 20 bytes".

Therefore, the second out-of-bounds access will cause errors at runtime, but the first out-of-bounds access may not necessarily cause problems (depending on the system)

The effect of my test here is that when the boundary is exceeded, Sometimes an error will be reported when running the program, but sometimes it will not (the code remains unchanged).

Anyway, **AddressSanitizer** that Igor recommend can 100% solves the problem on your side, here is how to turn on it:

1, Right click your CPP project, and then click "Properties"

[image]

2, Enable Address Sanitizer:

[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    int* a = new int[5];
    a[5] = 0;
}
```

The difference from before is that now it is 100% possible to detect problems that exceed the scope of the heap on the right, instead of looking at the stack on the left:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, and @Igor too.  AdressSanitizer works perfectly, solved my problem. I had to disable other features for it to function, but its explained in microsoft's documentation.